# Placing a marker on Harp.gl map

Tags: marker, harp.gl

Can somebody share an example on how to place a simple marker on the harp-gl generated map? I can't find any information on how to achieve it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

here are two examples of markers for a point:

[harp.gl docs geojson points](https://www.harp.gl/docs/master/examples/#datasource_geojson_points.html)

[harp.gl docs lines and points](https://www.harp.gl/docs/master/examples/#datasource_features_lines-and-points.html)

On each of these web pages you can click the `</>` logo in the bottom right corner to see an example in JavaScript code.